# Converting String to Date error

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have date string value like this: Fri, 27-Sep-2013 08:29:59 GMT
And i need, to convert it in Date format
I tried like this:

```
private Date modifyDateLayout(String inputDate) {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        format.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone ("GMT"));
        Date d = null;
        try {
        d = format.parse(inputDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        return d;
    }
```

But it didn't work, and e=null
Where am I wrong?
Thanks for the help

Comment: 1) try DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); without 'T' and set timezone before setting a date template.
2)Maybe incoming String is not valid

May be this http://java67.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-format-date-in-java-simpledateformat-example.html help you

Comment: first solution doesn't work too... The String is valid, I copied string in question from debug

Answer (score 2):

Try this works perfectly

```
private Date modifyDateLayout(String inputDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = format.parse(inputDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return d;
    }
```

**Call**

```
modifyDateLayout("Fri, 27-Sep-2013 08:29:59 GMT");
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know reason, but steel returns null. Even full copy of you answer, and I can't understood this... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The format should be `EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
System.out.println(format.format(now));
String s = format.format(now);
String result = s.substring(0, 26) + ":" + s.substring(27);
System.out.println("Result: "+result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your format. `EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ`

Here is the [working output](http://ideone.com/zWX2ct).

Comment: I can't understand... I copied all you code (even with string const) and steel don't work!

Comment: in catch e = null! :o

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
private Date modifyDateLayout(String inputDate) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = format.parse(inputDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // To change body of catch statement use File |
                                // Settings | File Templates.
    }
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working. Just set your time according to GMT and it will give you your local time.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class Time {
    private Date modifyDateLayout(String inputDate) {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");
        format.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone ("GMT"));

        Date d = null;
        try {
        d = format.parse(inputDate);
        System.out.println(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        return d;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new Time().modifyDateLayout("Fri, 27-Sep-2013 08:29:59 GMT");
        new Time().modifyDateLayout("Fri, 17-Apr-2015 15:45:59 GMT");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vitality you had made mistake in your second line DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");